# Visual Studio not building a dependency of a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependency-management, dll-dependency

I have a project which consists of window services projects and a logic project for each one.

Let's say my windows service project is called `Project1` and it has a logic project called `Project1BL`. If I build `Project1`, it builds `Project1BL` AND `Project1` which is good.

My problem is with another project in this solution (`Project2`) if I build it and `Project2BL` is not built it throws an error

> Metadata file Project2BL/bin/debug/Project2BL.dll not found

I don't want to have to build `Project2BL` explicitly each time I build the solution.

Anyone has an idea why would one project give me this issue while another project doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

I evetually fixed it by simply removing the project "Project2BL" from the solution and readding it. It moved the decleration of the project in the .sln to the bottom and that solved it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `Project2BL` is an assembly reference for `Project2`, and not a project reference.  What you could try doing is removing the reference to `Project2BL`, then add it back as a project reference.  So with Visual Studio 2010, in the `Project2` project, you would expand the References folder, right-click `Project2BL` and choose "Remove".  Then you would right-click the References folder, choose "Add Reference", then click the "Projects" tab, and choose `Project2BL` from the list and click "OK".  This adds `Project2BL` as a project reference.  What this means is that whenever you build `Project2`, the build process knows that it must first build the `Project2BL` project, and so you won't have to explicitly build it.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening your solution's properties, then select

**Common Properties** - **Project Dependencies**.

Select **Project2** and check **Project2BL** as the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Although I have added the build dependency the dependency was still not showing. The reference was not added.

I fixed this through: **Dependencies -> Add Reference -> Projects.**